# Fechas en Angular TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

Como puedo configurar la fecha para que en la parte de mes me arroje `ejemplo = "2021-05-24"` pero este código me arroja `"2021-5-24"` y **quiero que me salga el 0 del mes**

```
let fecha = new Date();

    console.log(fecha);
    

    let desdeStr = `${fecha.getFullYear()}-${fecha.getMonth()+1}-${fecha.getDate()}`;

    console.log(desdeStr);
```

Se que si agrego `0${fecha.getMonth()+1}` funciona pero cuando llegue el mes 10-11-12 me va a arrojar `010-011-012` y no quiero eso. **¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?**

```
let desdeStr = `${fecha.getFullYear()}-0${fecha.getMonth()+1}-${fecha.getDate()}`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el método **slice**, en este caso el mes 10 no va a mostrarte 010 debido a que extraes solamente los dos últimos elementos usando **slice(-2)**. Entonces omites el cero cuando el mes ya tiene dos cifras pero no cuando el mes tiene una cifra ya que ahí le concatenas el cero.

```
let desdeStr = `${fecha.getFullYear()}-${('0'+(fecha.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)}-${fecha.getDate()}`;
```

Comment: Gracias bro si funciona

Answer (score 0):

Angular tiene una función para formatear fechas:

```
let fecha = formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en-US')
```

[Referencia](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate)

Comment: Gracias bro funciona